# Getting GCC linker to warn about multiple function definitions

Tags: gcc, warnings, symbols, one-definition-rule

Consider my small example C library:

```
#include <external_library.h>

void some_function(void)
{
    external_library_call();
    // Do other stuff...
}
```

It plans to make some_function() publicly callable. The library doesn't work, though, because the external library it requires also happens to use a function called some_function(), which happens to have the same prototype. GCC's linker doesn't care how many sources of the some_function symbol there are, though. It picks one seemingly at random and the external library may or may not use my some_function() instead of its own. This is insane. Not the fact that the library doesn't work. This library definitely shouldn't work. It's more the fact that there are two sources for the symbol 'some_function', but the linker doesn't do anything about it. And you know, that doesn't bother me too much because I'm used to GCC and C in general being pathologically reckless by default. There's gotta be a way, though, to get the linker to warn me when there are two sources for the same symbol. I've already tried -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow, but that doesn't produce any warnings.

Note that -fvisibility=hidden won't help here because both libraries want to export some_function(). I know you can just say shame on me for making  function calls without a unique prefix. You're right. It's a mistake. I don't care. This mistake is catchable by the linker and so should be caught. There is no reason why the linker shouldn't catch this mistake. Besides, the library you're using might export some weird unexpected symbols, and you do not necessarily have control over what somebody else's library exports. That and prefixes can only be made so unique before the programmer halts and catches fire.

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
-fvisibility=hidden
```

To your build flags. Note some caveats, however; some headers might not be expecting this. In those cases, you need to use a pragma before including them:

```
#pragma GCC visibility push(hidden)
#include <problematic_header>
#pragma GCC visibility pop
```

There are some other benefits to this other than just avoiding symbol collisions. See:

http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

In case you're interested.

Comment: If I read this correctly, I must also add __attribute__((visibility("default"))) in front of main() to export it. Correct?

Comment: @enigmaticPhysicist I don't think so. main() seems to be treated specially by GCC and always exported.

Comment: Though this is very helpful and I'll definitely use this, it does not solve the original problem. The linker /knew/ there were two separate instances of the same symbol. Why didn't it halt and deliver an error? Why did it choose one and not the other? What were the criteria? What if I need to export a symbol and I want to be sure it does *not* collide with any of the other symbols I'm using? I still call this problem not solved until I can get the linker to halt with error under such a condition.

Comment: @enigmaticPhysicist This did answer the question before you hijacked it and edited it. Now it asks something different. You should have posted a new question instead.

Comment: It currently asks what I'd meant to ask all along. You misunderstood me in the first place because I wasn't clear the first time I wrote it. I think I would know what I meant, having asked the question in the first place. This is not hijacking.

Comment: @enigmaticPhysicist Well, pretty much no one is going to see your edited question, because it's years old. The answer was correct for the application use-case, but not for the library use-case. So if you want a good chance of having the new question answered, you should restore this question to its original state and create a new question for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Options such as `-Wall -Wextra -Wshadow` are compiler flags that affect the analysis of the source code; apparently, you're after a linker option.

However, since `shutdown()` is in the namespace reserved for the application to use (and you don't even show that you've included the header that does declare the system `shutdown()`), there is nothing much the compiler or linker can do.  You as the application programmer are entitled to create a function called `shutdown()` and call it.  You could look at something like the LSB (Linux Standards Base) compliance suite to check that you aren't defining functions that are defined by the implementation.

One of the harder bugs I ever had to track down involved a function `_bind()` in our code that happened to be the same name as a system function `_bind()` that had a different interface.  When our function was called by parts of the system library, all hell broke loose.  That was partly our fault for using a name reserved to the system (don't start variable or function names with `_`), it was unfortunate that only one platform had the name collision.  A systematic prefix to our `_bind()` resolved the issue.

You could look at the lists of reserved names in the C and POSIX standards.  However, you'd find that the `_t` suffix is reserved, but type names with the suffix are widely (ab)used for user-defined types too.  You also have to know whether any given definition of the type is 'from a system header' (presumably OK), or from a user-defined header (probably not OK), or is a 'user-defined header providing missing system functionality' (border-line).  It gets very tricky.

Comment: About the _bind() bug: I don't think it was your fault at all. At some point, the linker must have realised there were two definitions of _bind(). There is just no way the linker didn't know this. Unless there are some finnicky details about the linker's operation I am unfamiliar with...

Comment: Actually, was it that the linker on compile time never checked the symbol tables of the shared objects that it was linking? That's the only explanation I can think of. Even then, it's still kind of reckless.